# What is the best and simplest option to setup a Linux VIP

Tags: linux, networking, redhat

I just wondered if anyone could suggest some software and maybe provide example of how to setup a VIP between two servers?

Basically the problem is i want to setup two access servers with a VIP so that users can go to one address / ip, then it sends that the the current active host for login.

I have setup UCARP before with mysql, but not sure if this is the best option and what to monitor etc...

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have failover, then pacemmaker is likely what you a looking for. It can be used to have a ip that will be floating between 2 servers in a passive/active setup.

And it take care of stopping and restarting services.

UCARP is mainly for firewall, IIRC, and work well too; You need to share connexion table with ctsync if you do not want to have active connection cut however.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want other than moving the VIP from one server to the other in case of failure? There are many HA solutions for Linux system such as [heartbeat](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat) and [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/). They are good and stable.

Comment: So i just want the VIP to move if the system stops responding (EG wont accept people connecting to it or logging in), thats pretty much it.